# Notify comment author upon reply

Tags: plugins, php, comments, email, notifications

To improve communication between guest commenters and authors, I am fiddling with a script that sends an email to the author of a comment when it receives a reply.

Here is how the code looks so far:

```
<?php
/* 
Plugin Name: Comment Reply Notifier
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/24875/christine-cooper
Version: 0.1
Author: Christine Cooper
Description: When someone replies to a comment, an email is sent to the writer of the replied comment.
Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/24875/christine-cooper
*/

add_action('comment_post', 'comment');
function comment($comment_reply_id) 
{
    $comment = get_comment($comment_reply_id);
    if($comment->comment_parent != 0) 
    {
        $old_comment = get_comment($comment->comment_parent);
        if($old_comment->user_id == 0)
        {
            $email = $old_comment->comment_author_email;
            $name = $comment->comment_author;
            $content = $comment->comment_content;
            $post = get_post($comment->comment_post_ID);
            $title = $post->post_title;
            $link = get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID);
            $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
            $subject = sprintf('Comment reply: "%2$s" at %1$s', $blogname, $title );
            $notify_message  = sprintf('Someone replied to a comment you left on: %s', $title ) . "\r\n";
            $notify_message .= sprintf( 'Reply by: %1$s ', $name ) . "\r\n";
            $notify_message .= 'Comment: ' . "\r\n" . $content . "\r\n\r\n";
            $notify_message .= 'You can reply to the comment here: ' . "\r\n";
            $notify_message .= $link . "#comments\r\n\r\n";
            $message_headers = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"" . get_option('blog_charset') . "\"\n";
            wp_mail( $email, $subject, $notify_message, $message_headers );
        }
    } 
}

?>
```

It works fine, feel free to try it. There are two things I want to add to it. I want to adjust the name and the email of the message. So I want to set the Blog name as the name of the sender and a custom email as the sender's mail (for instance no-reply@domain.com). How do I do it?

Comment: Ok, but how is that better than e.g. 'uComment', 'Send email only on Reply to My Comment' or 'Comment Reply Notifier'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you need to use header to perform the sender... by default the sender is wordpress@yousite.domain

```
$headers = 'From: My Name <myname@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";
```

...

```
wp_mail( $email, $headers, $subject, $notify_message, $message_headers );
```

Edited... source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

Comment: What about the sender name?

Comment: ok.. its seems easier then it looks like. Now dunno if it works. Feel free to edit mu answer and improve it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. It appears that `$sender` replaced the title of the message, not the actual email that it was sent from and the name of the sender.

Comment: Maybe it is related to `headers`? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

Comment: ahahha..we saw both same time. yea..was cheking that as well :D answer was updated.

Comment: I tried `$message_headers = 'From: My Name <myname@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";` but still didn't work, which is very strange.